# Access 32 bit com object in 64 bit machines in python

Tags: python, com, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am in a situation where I need to automate an application which is 32 bit.I chose python to do that and it worked well on 32 bit but on 64 bit systems it is not working.The reason being 64 bit python is unable to see the 32 bit registry entry for the ProgId of my application to be automated.So, when i use
q=win32com.client.Dispatch("MyApplicationProgId") I get
"Invalid class string"

I did some google and find this solution but this dint work as well.
http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

I then try installing 32 bit python on 64 bit machines which has 64 bit python installed already.But this also doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I have no problem automating 32 bit servers from 64 bit code, and vice versa.